# grep substring between two delimiters

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep, busybox

I have a lot of `bash` scripts that use `perl` expressions within `grep` in order to extract a substring between two delimiters. Example:

```
echo BeginMiddleEnd | grep -oP '(?<=Begin).*(?=End)'
```

The problem is, when I ported these scripts to a platform running `busybox`, 'integrated' `grep` does not recognize -P switch. Is there a clean way to do this using `grep` and `regular expressions`?

Edit:
There is no `perl`, `sed` or `awk` on that platform. It's a lightweight `linux`.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use Perl?

Comment: there is no `perl` on that platform, only basic tools, primarily ones from `busybox`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming there's no more than one occurrence per line, you can use

```
sed -nr 's/.*Begin(.*)End.*/\1/p'
```

With grep and non-greedy quantifier you could also print more than one per line.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `awk` with custom field separator like this to get same output:

```
echo 'BeginMiddleEnd' | awk -F 'Begin|End' '{print $2}'
Middle
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation wouldn't hurt ;). The -F option seems to be the field separator... but what magic is the `|` doing in `-F 'Begin|End'`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `bash` built-in parameter substitution:

```
# grab some string from grep output
f=BeginMiddleEnd
middleend=${f/Begin/}    # do some substitution to lose "Begin"

echo $middleend
MiddleEnd

beginmiddle=${f%%End}    # strip from right end to lose "End"
echo $beginmiddle
BeginMiddle
```

Loads more examples [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).