# replace dots in a string from file bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to replace a string in a file, the content is as below:

```
node11d:hostname1:KY home node11d 202014
node2:hostname1:KY home node2 202014
node3c1:hostname1:KY home node3c1 202014
```

I want this output:

```
hostname1 home node11d 202014
hostname1 home node2 202014
hostname1 home node3c1 202014
```

Thanks!

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you already tried and what problems did you face? Please read [ask]. FWIW you could use `sed` or `awk`. Here's a similar question: [grep substring between two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26347404/4518341)

Comment: This really doesn't need an attempt. Basic awk and sed questions are reasonable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F"[: ]" '{print $2,$4,$5,$6}' yourfile
```

This is just splitting each row up by either a colon or a space (into columns) then it prints out the 2nd, 4th, 5th, and 6th column. Obviously if your file differs in numbers of columns based on this split then you'll have to get more creative.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat foo.txt | awk '{gsub(/ /,":");print}' | awk -F":" '{print $2,$4,$5,$6}' > new_foo.txt
```